# Array of pointers storing string in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to C language. Recently I have come across several problems regarding pointers. Would like to seek your help. Thank you very much~

Below is a code block:

```
char *a[2];
a[0] = "blah";
a[1] = "hmm";
printf("%s %d\n", a[0],a[0]);
printf("%s %d\n", a[1], a[1]);
```

Output of the above codes is "blah", address of a[0],"hmm" and address of a[1].

First question is: a[0] is supposed to be a pointer, which should contain an address. But here a[0] is assigned with a string, which is strange. Why this works?

Second question is: a[0] is a pointer, therefore printf("%d",a[0]) will naturally print the address of a[0]. However, printf("%s",a[0]) prints "blah", which is the string stored in the address whose address value is equal to the value stored in a[0]. Intuitively I think the correct syntax to print the string is to use printf("%s",*(a[0])) , which turns out to be execution error. So why printf("%s",a[0]) gives the desired string result?

Looking forward to your answers and really appreciate your help~

Comment: Do not be surprised -- C is primitive,  inconsistent and archaic. The whole pointer/array thing is a single clusterf*ck. There are no strings, strictly speaking; what C people call strings (hey, it was 1978!) are just arrays with a convention (last byte is 0). As I said elsewhere, I find google an immensely helpful tool. I googled for you with the rather obvious words "c character string tutorial". Unsurprisingly, the first result seems helpful. I would include a "lmgtfy" link here but SO forbids that, which is sad.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. printf("%s %d\n", a[0],a[0]);

You should use `%p` to print pointers. `%d` is to print integers.

---

> 2. a[0] is supposed to be a pointer, which should contain an address. But here a[0] is assigned with a string, which is strange. Why this works?

Yes. `a[0]` is supposed to be a pointer, which should contain an address. Assigning `a[0]` to a string works because string constant is a pointer to it's first member. i.e. "blah" is a pointer to `b`

To verify:

```
printf("%p\n", "blah");
```

---

> 3. a[0] is a pointer, therefore printf("%d",a[0]) will naturally print the address of a[0]. However, printf("%s",a[0]) prints "blah", which is the string stored in the address whose address value is equal to the value stored in a[0].

`printf("%p", a[0])` will print the value of `a[0]` which is an address and `printf("%s", a[0])` will print a string stored linearly starting from address `a[0]`. This is because of `format specifier` used.

`%p` says print the value as address (pointer) wheres `%s` says print all the characters stored starting from `a[0]` till `\0` character encounters.

---

> 4. Intuitively I think the correct syntax to print the string is to use printf("%s",*(a[0])) , which turns out to be execution error.

`a[0]` is a pointer, an address. We have character `b` from `"blah"` stored at that address. So the type of `*(a[0])` is `char` wheres `"%s"` expects type `char *` (a pointer to character).  So type mismatch.

To get the clear idea:

```
printf("%c",*(a[0]));
```

This will print the character stored at `a[0]` as we are dereferencing `a[0]` using `*` operator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it does really help! As for the second point, I am curious if this is the same to array of int. So I tried "int* b[2]; b[0]={1,2};", which is incorrect expression. So it seems that string is somewhat special. Do u know anything about it?

Comment: @J.Lin When you say `int *b[2]` or `char *b[2]` it just means *create an array named `b` of pointer to int/char with array_size=2*.
Now `int *b[2] = {&i, &j};` is correct where `i` and `j` are ints and `&i` and `&j` are `int *`s

Comment: For `char *b[2] = {ptr, nptr};` is valid where `ptr` and `nptr` are pointer to chars which may be defined as `char *ptr = "blah"` and `char *nptr = &c` where `c` is a `char`

Comment: The type of  "blah" is `char *` as *string constant is a pointer to it's first member.* The type of `&c` is also `char *`. Hope this clarifies

Comment: I now do understand string constant is a pointer to its first member. But string is essentially an array of characters. So why "int* b[2]; b[0]={1,2};" doesn't work? I mean {1,2} is an array of int,  so why {1,2}, an int array constant,  is not a pointer to its first member? What makes string constant special?

Comment: `{1, 2}` is *not* an array of `int`s as `{'a', 'b'}` is *not* an array of `char`s. `b[2]={'a', 'b'};` will also give an error because `{'a', 'b'}` is *not* an array. That notation is a special notation which is only used for *initializing* the array as `char foo[] = {'a', 'b'}`;

Answer (score 2):

A string literal is actually an array of characters, which includes the terminating null character. And as all arrays, the string literal array can decay to a pointer to its first element.

And all string handling in C is using pointers to the first character, and then simply just increase the "index" until it finds the terminating character.

Also note that using the `"%d"` format for printing pointers is *undefined*, you should be using the `"%p"` format.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer~